# Ember: Reset a model-bound-form on transition

Tags: ember.js

I would like to reset unsaved changes on a form when transitioning. Is there a standard, non-convoluted way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

yes, `record.rollback()` will reset any unsaved changes on a record

Comment: How do I execute this whenever a "link-to" href is clicked?